# Can I check: x, y in string in ONE if statement without using additional elifs

Tags: python

I don't understand how to check it a string contains multiple variables (in my case X or Y char):

```
if self.game_field[0][0] and self.game_field[0][1] and self.game_field[0][2] == "X", "Y":
```

So, `game_field` is a multidimensional array, and via `if` I am checking the combinations to win. Simply put, I am implementing a banal game of tic-tac-toe, and I need to check the winning combinations. I Know that this can be checked using tuples,
but I'm wondering if it's possible to check by writing this in one line: do all three variables contain the value of either X or Y (a strict match), without using additional `elif`s.

Comment: You can use `set` to check for intersections of two or more values. You can use `in` if looking for either-or.

Comment: `a and b and c == "X"` doesn't check that all three variables are equal to `"X"` Related: [Why does `a == b or c or d` always evaluate to True?](//stackoverflow.com/q/20002503/843953) and [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/843953) You need to write them out individually: `a == "X" and b == "X" and c == "X"`

Comment: `"".join(self.game_field[0]) in ("XXX", "YYY")` is another option but needs `self.game_field[0]`'s entries to be strings. Checks whether their concatenation equals to either triplet.

Comment: @MustafaAydın That's a very interesting approach. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @MustafaAydın Actually it can also just be `self.game_field[0] in (['X' * 3], ['Y' * 3])` (assuming `game_field` is a list of lists)...

Comment: @Tomerikoo As I understand, a slight correction is needed as `([*"X"*3], [*"Y"*3])` (unless they store as 1-element lists). In this case I thought `"".join` & matching against strings themselves might be more readable. But it requires entries be strings and it is not clear from the question if they are, so I think not worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide the problem to two:

1. check that all three variables have the same value.
2. check that this value is either X or Y.

To do that, you can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set), which ignores duplicates. So if all three variables have the same value, the set's size will be exactly one. Then, we can check that this single value is either X or Y:

```py
row_values = set(self.game_field[0])
if len(row_values) == 1 and row_values.pop() in {'X', 'Y'}:
    # do something
```

---

A different approach could be to use the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) built-in function to check that *all* values share the same value:

```py
if all(cell == 'X' for cell in self.game_field[0]) or all(cell == 'Y' for cell in self.game_field[0]):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (self.game_field[0][0] == "X" and self.game_field[0][1] == "X" and self.game_field[0][2] == "X") or (self.game_field[0][0] == "Y" and self.game_field[0][1] == "Y" and self.game_field[0][2] == "Y"):
```

I think this is what you're looking for? Either all three fields are X, or all three are Y.